# Postgresql: In-Row vs Out-of-Row for text/varchar

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, text, varchar

Two part question:

1. What is Postgresql behavior for storing text/varchars in-row vs
   out-of-row? Am I correct in thinking that with default settings, all columns will always be stored in-row until the 2kB size is reached?
2. Do we have any control over the above behavior? Is there any way I can change the threshold for a specific column/table, or force a specific column to always be stored out-of-row?

I've read through PostGresql Toast documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/storage-toast.html), but I don't see any option for changing the thresholds (default seems to be 2kB-for-row) or for forcing a column to always store out-of-row (EXTERNAL only allows it, but doesn't enforce it).

I've found documentation explaining how to do this on SQL Server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173530.aspx), but don't see anything similar for PostGresql.

---

If anyone's interested in my motivation, I have a table that has a mix of short-consistent columns (IDs, timestamps etc), a column that is varchar(200), and a column that is text/varchar(max), which can be extremely large in length. I currently have both varchars stored in a separate table, just to allow efficient storage/lookups/scanning on the short-consistent columns.

This is a pain however, because I constantly have to do joins to read all the data. I would really like to store all the above fields in the same table, and tell Postgresql to force-store the 2 VARCHARs out-of-row, always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

For first part of the question: you are correct (see for instance [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST)).

For the second part of the question: the standard way of storing columns is to compress variable length text fields if their size is over 2KB, and eventually store them into a separate area, called “TOAST table”.

You can give a “hint” to the system on how to store a field by using the following command for your columns:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ALTER COLUMN YourColumn SET STORAGE (PLAIN | EXTENDED | EXTERNAL | MAIN)
```

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html):

> `SET STORAGE`
>
> This form sets the storage mode for a column. This controls whether this column is held inline or in a secondary TOAST table, and whether the data should be compressed or not. `PLAIN` must be used for fixed-length values such as integer and is inline, uncompressed. `MAIN` is for inline, compressible data. `EXTERNAL` is for external, uncompressed data, and `EXTENDED` is for external, compressed data. `EXTENDED` is the default for most data types that support non-PLAIN storage. Use of `EXTERNAL` will make substring operations on very large text and bytea values run faster, at the penalty of increased storage space. Note that `SET STORAGE` doesn't itself change anything in the table, it just sets the strategy to be pursued during future table updates. See Section 59.2 for more information.

Since the manual is not completely explicit on this point, this is my interpretation: the final decision about how to store the field is left in any case to the system, given the following constraints:

1. No field can be stored such that the total size of a row is over
   8KB
2. No field is stored out-of-row if its size is less then the
   `TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD`
3. After satisfying the previous
   constraints, the system tries to satisfy the `SET STORAGE` strategy
   specified by the user. If no storage strategy is specified, each TOAST-able
   field is automatically declared `EXTENDED`.

Under these assumption, the only way to be sure that *all* the values of a column are stored out-of-row is to recompile the system with a value of `TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD` less then the minumum size of *any* value of the column.

Comment: According to the following (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/storage-toast.html): The TOAST code is triggered only when a row value to be stored in a table is wider than TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD bytes (normally 2 kB). EXTENDED allows both compression and out-of-line storage. This is the default for most TOAST-able data types. Compression will be attempted first, then out-of-line storage if the row is still too big.

This seems to imply that the column will be stored out-of-row, only if it exceeds ~2kB. Is there any way to force it to always get stored out-of-row?

Comment: The behaviour described in the page you referenced is the *automatic* behaviour of PostgreSQL. The strategy that I suggested in the answer *forces* the system to follow the storage strategy that you want (see for instance this [discussion](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Modifying-TOAST-TUPLE-THRESHOLD-and-TOAST-TUPLE-TARGET-td2008661.html)). The only other possibility is recompiling a private copy of PostgreSQL to change the parameter `TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD`, but this is only the last resort. Note that you have to reload the table if you apply the `ALTER COLUMN` solution (read the manual!).

Comment: Are you sure that `ALTER COLUMN SET STORAGE EXTENDED` *forces* the system to store the data out-of-row?

According to the manual: `EXTENDED is for external, compressed data. EXTENDED is the default for most data types that support non-PLAIN storage` Ie, extended is *already* the default for varchar(max), so I wouldn't have expected the command to do anything. That same section also refers us to 58.2, which states `strategies for storing TOAST-able columns: Extended...Compression will be attempted first, then out-of-line storage if the row is still too big.`